# synchronizing 2 fifos from Vivado SDK

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I am experimenting with a zynq 7020 and Vivado 2016.1.
Trying this tutorial http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/using-the-axi-dma-in-vivado.html is working so far.
(Simple example using AXI DMA and AXI4-Stream Data FIFO)

Expanding this example using 2 fifos is working also in the same way.
So using "XPAR_AXIDMA_0_DEVICE_ID" and "XPAR_AXIDMA_1_DEVICE_ID" in the sdk is working.

Using this is just an academic example and some kind of worthless.
The sense of using 2 FIFOs is combining the output for floating point IP or something like this.

My question is how to fill both fast enough and synchronouse to use them in the right order in the sdk?

As a simple example:
fill both FIFOs with numbers [1 2 3 4 5...]
add them with the floating point IP
read result [2 4 6 8...]